# testing non-exported methods in python

Tags: python, testing, directory-structure

My code is organized this way:

```
app/sampling
├── __init__.py
├── filters.py
└── test
    └── filters_test.py
```

On `filters.py` there are some exported functions (included in `__init__.py`) and some unexported functions, that begin with underscore.

On `filters_test.py` I have no trouble testing the exported functions, that I can access like this:

```
from app.sampling import exported_function
```

(note that "app" is part of my *PYTHONPATH*)

But then if I try to import a private function like this:

```
from ..filters import _private_function
```

This seems to work but then on runtime:

`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Additional notes:

- I'm using nose for running the tests
- I'd like to keep the folder structure if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from app.sampling.filters import _private_function